# How to test CDI injection contains @inject and @any in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, cdi

I would like to write unit test for this class as below. I have no idea to mock or do any thing to get all implements of interface ConnectDatabase:

```
  @Inject
  @Any
  private Instance<ConnectDatabase> allConnectType;


    public class DAOUtils {
  public DAOUtils() {
    System.out.println("Constructor...");
  }
  @Inject
  @Any
  private Instance<ConnectDatabase> allConnectType;
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("PostConstruct...");
  }
  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Destroy!");
  }
  public void query() {
    for (ConnectDatabase conn : allConnectType) {
      conn.connect();
    }
    System.out.println("query database...");
  }
}
```

interface:

```
public interface ConnectDatabase {
   public void connect();
}
```

Does anyone has any ideas? Thank you

Comment: There is [CDI-Unit](http://cdi-unit.github.io/cdi-unit/) and [Weld JUnit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit), if it helps.

Comment: Unittests verify the behaviro of **your** code. The Injection is behavior of the *injection framework* and therefore not subject to Unittests. For this we set up Integration tests.